# how to change product status when product is out of stock?(publish to pending review)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In woocommerce, if out of stock then product will be publish to pending product status.

I tried Product publish(Using following code) and then it become pending, but automatically it cant change status.

```php
add_action(
    'woocommerce_product_object_updated_props',
    'change_status_on_product_object_product'
);

function change_status_on_product_object_product($product, $updated_props) {
    $stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();
    $changed_props = $product->get_changes();
    if ($product->get_status() !== 'pending' && ($stock < 1)) {
        update_post_meta(array('ID' => $product->get_id(), 'post_status' => 'pending'));
    }
}
```

Comment: When should this status change take place? after the order, when the product becomes sold out or when you manually edit and save the product?

Comment: once product out of stock, then publish product will be draft or pending review

Comment: That doesn't fully answer my question. A product can go "out of stock" (automatically) after a customer places an order. But you can also manually adjust the "out of stock" status via the product edit settings. 
**In which case should the change (publish to pending) take place?** 
Since two separate codes would be needed for both situations.

Comment: product out of stock case, I want to change product post status to draft or pending(It will automatic), whenever product is in stock, admin will again publish that product

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'fields'         => 'ids', // duplicate - not assigned
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(

            'key'    => '_stock_status',
            'value'  => 'outofstock',
        )

    ),
);

$loop_arg            = new WP_Query( $args );

$loop_ids            = $loop_arg->posts;

foreach($loop_ids as $loop      => $loop_id){
   
    wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $loop_id, 
                  'post_status' => 'pending' ) );
    wp_reset_query();
    echo "<script>console.log('Product updating from publish to pending');</script>";
}
```